# Como solucionar "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"

Tags: sql-server, function

Estoy en la creación de una función Tabla valor en la cual estoy haciendo uso de un campo `DATEENTER` de tipo `Datetime`, pero al momento de ejecutar mi función me genera el siguiente mensaje de error:

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

La función de la que estoy haciendo uso en SQL Server es la siguiente:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Function_TotalTravel](
    @YearTravel SMALLINT = 0,
    @MonthTravel SMALLINT = 0
)
RETURNS @Tabla TABLE (
    Travel VARCHAR(20),
    StatusTravel VARCHAR(20),
    DATEENTER DATETIME,
    IdStatusTravel INT
)
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO @Tabla (Travel,StatusTravel,DATEENTER,IdStatusTravel)
SELECT  V.Travel,
        V.DATEENTER,
        
            CASE    WHEN V.TravelIncomplete = 1 THEN 'Travel Incomplete'
                    ELSE CASE 
                    WHEN V.StatusTravel = 2 THEN 'Transit'
                    WHEN V.StatusTravel = 3 THEN 'Closed'
                    WHEN V.StatusTravel = 4 THEN 'Cancel'
                    ELSE CAST(V.StatusTravel AS VARCHAR)
                    END END as 'StatusTravel',
            CASE    WHEN V.TravelIncomplete = 1 THEN 99
            ELSE    V.StatusTravel END IdStatusTravel
            
    FROM    TblTravel V WITH(NOLOCK)
    WHERE   (DATEPART(YearTravel, V.DATEENTER) = @YearTravel OR @YearTravel = 0)
    AND     (DATEPART(MONTH, V.DATEENTER) = @MonthTravel OR @MonthTravel = 0)
    AND  ((V.StatusTravel NOT IN (0,1) AND V.TravelIncomplete = 0) OR V.TravelIncomplete = 1)

    RETURN
END
```

Intente realizar un `CONVERT` en el select de la función de la siguiente manera:

```
convert(varchar,DATEENTER),
```

Pero este me devuelve el mismo mensaje de error, alguna otra solución que me puedan sugerir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás insertando las columnas en el orden incorrecto. Tratas de insertar `StatusTravel` en `DATEENTER` y viceversa. Solo tienes que cambiar el orden y debe funcionar.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Function_TotalTravel](
    @YearTravel SMALLINT = 0,
    @MonthTravel SMALLINT = 0
)
RETURNS @Tabla TABLE (
    Travel VARCHAR(20),
    StatusTravel VARCHAR(20),
    DATEENTER DATETIME,
    IdStatusTravel INT
)
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO @Tabla (Travel,DATEENTER,StatusTravel,IdStatusTravel) --Este orden debe coincidir con el del SELECT
SELECT  V.Travel,
        V.DATEENTER,
    
            CASE    WHEN V.TravelIncomplete = 1 THEN 'Travel Incomplete'
                    ELSE CASE 
                    WHEN V.StatusTravel = 2 THEN 'Transit'
                    WHEN V.StatusTravel = 3 THEN 'Closed'
                    WHEN V.StatusTravel = 4 THEN 'Cancel'
                    ELSE CAST(V.StatusTravel AS VARCHAR)
                    END END as 'StatusTravel',
            CASE    WHEN V.TravelIncomplete = 1 THEN 99
            ELSE    V.StatusTravel END IdStatusTravel
        
    FROM    TblTravel V WITH(NOLOCK)
    WHERE   (DATEPART(YearTravel, V.DATEENTER) = @YearTravel OR @YearTravel = 0)
    AND     (DATEPART(MONTH, V.DATEENTER) = @MonthTravel OR @MonthTravel = 0)
    AND  ((V.StatusTravel NOT IN (0,1) AND V.TravelIncomplete = 0) OR V.TravelIncomplete = 1)

    RETURN
END
```

Como dato adicional, puedes obtener un mejor rendimiento si conviertes la función a una función en línea.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Function_TotalTravel](
    @YearTravel SMALLINT = 0,
    @MonthTravel SMALLINT = 0
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
SELECT  V.Travel,
        V.DATEENTER,
        CASE    WHEN V.TravelIncomplete = 1 THEN 'Travel Incomplete'
                WHEN V.StatusTravel = 2 THEN 'Transit'
                WHEN V.StatusTravel = 3 THEN 'Closed'
                WHEN V.StatusTravel = 4 THEN 'Cancel'
                ELSE CAST(V.StatusTravel AS VARCHAR(20)) END AS StatusTravel,
        CASE    WHEN V.TravelIncomplete = 1 THEN 99
                ELSE V.StatusTravel END                     AS IdStatusTravel
        
    FROM    TblTravel V WITH(NOLOCK)
    WHERE   (DATEPART(YearTravel, V.DATEENTER) = @YearTravel OR @YearTravel = 0)
    AND     (DATEPART(MONTH, V.DATEENTER) = @MonthTravel OR @MonthTravel = 0)
    AND  ((V.StatusTravel NOT IN (0,1) AND V.TravelIncomplete = 0) OR V.TravelIncomplete = 1);
```

Comment: Gracias por la corrección, no había revisado el orden de las columnas, una duda adicional, en que afecta el rendimiento si lo paso a una función en línea ?

Comment: Las funciones son objetos costosos en SQL Server. Previenen el paralelismo y se llaman una vez por cada fila. Al convertirlas en función en línea tienen la capacidad de integrarse a la consulta principal y obtener un mejor plan de ejecución que tome en cuenta lo que pasa dentro de la función (similar a como funcionan las vistas).

Comment: Excelente respuesta, clara y concisa